# Bootstrap tooltip border issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap tooltip from here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
   <a class="my-logo" href="http://www.google.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip">
   <img src="/pathToImage.jpg" alt="image">
   </a>
</div>
```

When I tried it in IE, seems that a border appeared (if use `right` placement position) like in below picture:

[image: Bootstrap tooltip]

That image was taken from original bootstrap website.

Can you tell me how to fix it ?

I added

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

but same thing

Thanks

Comment: Which version of IE? If you believe that it's a bug, why not post an issue on github?

Comment: The 11th version of IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better solution but this should work.

Try adding somewhere (on bottom) in code:

```
.tooltip-inner{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

if that doesn't work try with !important:

```
.tooltip-inner{
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```